# Spotify OAuth getting "grant_type parameter is missing" for client_credentials flow

Tags: java, spotify

I am a new user to the Spotify restful API. I have code that works for the restful calls I want to use, but cannot get the authorization to work through my Java client. The error message returned is:

400: Bad Request

{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"grant_type parameter is missing"}

My code is:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) {

    getToken();

    System.out.println("<<< Finished >>>");

}

public static String getToken() {

    final String payload = "grant_type: client_credentials";
    final String unencodedCredential = CLIENT_ID + ':' + CLIENT_SECRET;
    final String encodedCredential   = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(unencodedCredential.getBytes());

    String response = "";
    try {
        final URL url = new URL("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token");
        try {
            final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredential);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
            connection.setRequestProperty("grant_type", "client_credentials");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + payload.length());
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            try (final DataOutputStream writer = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream())) {
                writer.writeChars(payload);
            }

            if (connection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()))) {
                    while (reader.ready()) {
                        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                    }
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println(connection.getResponseMessage());
                try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getErrorStream()))) {
                    while (reader.ready()) {
                        System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode() + ": " + connection.getResponseMessage());
                        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (final IOException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (final MalformedURLException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;

}
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing the issue?